# How to modify key values in std::map container

Tags: c++, stdmap

Given

```
std::map<int,std::string> myMap;
fillMyMapWithStuff(myMap);

// modify key values - I need to add a constant value to each key
for (std::map<int,std::string>::iterator mi=myMap.begin(); mi != myMap.end(); ++mi)
{
    // ...
}
```

Whats a good way apply some re-indexing? Must I remove the old entry and add a new one with the new key and old value?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like you are better off building a new map and swapping it afterward. You'll have only `n` insert operations instead of `n` deletions and `n` insertions.

Comment: +1, in this case, when the whole map is rebuilt, it's better than even erase + insert with hint.

Comment: To be fair, its n insert operations + 1 swap operation.

Comment: @Justin: But a swap should take a meaningless amount of time.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you have to remove the old entry and add a new one with the new key. Keys are not modifiable.

If you were modifying only one or a few elements, you could do it efficiently by hinting `map::insert` with the position of the new element. Since your new keys are sure to be located somewhere *after* the old keys, you can hint with the iterator that points at the old element. However, you'd have to take care not to re-evaluate the freshly-inserted keys (by iterating end to front for example), and in case of modifying the entire map, it's more efficient to just build a new one.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you must.  The key is const while it is in the map.

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll have to construct a new map. If you delete and add new keys within the loop, it might destroy the integrity of iterating over the set of old keys, and not touching the just-inserted keys. (Unless you know how your keys are distributed and put your own logic in there.)

```
std::map<int,std::string> myMap;
fillMyMapWithStuff(myMap);

std::map<int,std::string> newMap;

// modify key values - I need to add a constant value to each key
for (std::map<int,std::string>::iterator mi=myMap.begin(); mi != myMap.end(); ++mi)
{
    newMap[mi->first] = mi->second;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's one more option. If this operation is a significant feature of your collection, and performance is important, you can avoid copying the map altogether. You can create a class overloading `operator[]`, as well as other accessors and mutators, and add the current shift of the key value.