# Replace a key in a std::map

Tags: c++, dictionary

I'm using the std::map to save some stuff, the key is Guid*.

```
typedef boost::tuple<c_ptr, handler_ptr> ctuple;
typedef std::map<GUID *, ctuple> c_map;
```

My question is:
Do I have a way to change the key of an item in the std::map? **OTHER THAN** copy the existing data to a new item that have the new key and remove the prev/old item (with the old key)

Thanks

Comment: See also [How to modify key values in std::map container](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3884572/96780).

Comment: Other than copy? *Move* the data to the new item :-)

Comment: Assuming the map is internally implemented with a balanced binary tree, just "changing" the key data would destroy the purpose and the order of the tree.

The operations you listed are necessary to create a new item and delete / rebalance the tree.

Answer (score 4):

> Do I have a way to change the key of an item in the std::map?

No.

This is why `value_type` of `std::map<Key, Value>` is `std::pair<Key const, Value>` (notice `const` applied to `Key`).

Comment: So the only way would be:
ctuple tmp = c_map[oldKey];   c_map[NewKey]= tmp;     c_map.erase[oldKey];

Comment: @Joseph Yep, something like that. In C++11 you can use `std::move` to move the value instead of copying it if it is relatively expensive to copy.

Comment: thanks, I afraid that the std::move here not help. move from one map to other yes, but move the data between value in same map, i don't see it would be better to use move.