# How to change value in map<pair<int, int>, pair<int, int>> myMap?

Tags: c++, dictionary

I would like to ask if there is a way how to change a value in `map<pair<int, int>, pair<int, int>> myMap`? Thank you. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace a key in a std::map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25620178/replace-a-key-in-a-stdmap)

Comment: What is the problem you have? What have you tried so far and how it didin't work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the fastest way to change a key of an element inside std::map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743545/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-change-a-key-of-an-element-inside-stdmap)

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you want to specifically change in your `std::pair` value (I assume you know which `'key'` you want to refer):

To change the first sub-value of the value:

```
    myMap[key].first = 0; //or whatever int value you need
```

To change the second sub-value:

```
    myMap[key].second = 0; //or whatever int value you need
```

To change the whole value (replace it with a new pair):

```
    myMap[key] = std::make_pair(0, 0); //or whatever int values you need
```

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple as long as you have a key.

```
pair<int, int> key = <some key>;
myMap[key] = <some new value>;
```

Comment: I am sorry, it is value. :D I have edited the question.

Comment: With modern C++, you can even do things like `myMap[{x,y}] = {p,q};`

Comment: @bloody, that's a place holder for valid new value.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all! And `myMap[key].first = 0;` works. :)